# Why is Kaa evil in almost every single adaption of the Jungle Books?

Tags: the-jungle-book-2016, mowgli-legend-of-the-jungle, the-jungle-book-1967

In nearly every adaption of the Jungle Books Kaa the snake is evil and attempts to kill and eat Mowgli. Is there a specific reason for why directors/writers of the movies try to turn Kaa evil, in spite of Kaa is one of Mowgli's trusted friends and mentors as depicted in the books?

I struggle to understand it as there are already plenty of villains: Bandar-Log, Shere-Khan, villagers, hunters and the Dhole.

Comment: This seems a very straightforward question to me - how does it need details or clarity?

Answer (score 6):

Because Walt Disney himself felt it would be better and audiences wouldn't sympathize with a snake being a *good guy*.

From [wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kaa),

> Kaa appears in the 1967 animated adaptation by Walt Disney
>   Productions. This version of Kaa is recast as an antagonist, as Walt
>   Disney felt audiences would not sympathize with a snake character.

this followed the Disney sequels/reboots (The Jungle Book 2(2003), The Jungle Book(1994), and 1967's remake The Jungle Book(2019) )